# Issue with an external library for a Web-Service on Axis2/Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, apache-axis, tomcat7

I have to **implement a web-service in Java and deploy it on a Tomcat server with Axis2**.

It work like a charm on my tomcat localhost and now I want to deploy it on a Tomcat server.

I use two Eclipse plugins :

- **Axis2 Code Generator** : to generate my WSDL
- **Axis2 Server Archiver** : to generate an archive aar to deploy my web-service

I installed axis2 on Tomcat server and I added the archive aar with the Admin module/Upload an Axis Service Archive File.

Axis2 correctly install the web-service and I can see the WSDL online on my Tomcat server.

**I restarted the server and now I try to consume an operation from my web-service but I have this error appear on screen :**

*"Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method identifierUtilisateur".*

**I watched to logs of my Tomcat server and I saw this exception :**

*"java.sql.SQLException : No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql"*

I know that I have a problem with the library "mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar" but when I generated the aar archive from eclipse I added the library as an external library source for the web-service.

When I open the arr archive the library is correctly placed in the folder /lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.

I try to put the library in the folder lib of tomcat (/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/lib/) and in the folder lib of axis (/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/lib/) but it still doesn't work.

Now I'm stuck on this exception and I can't progress in my project. I don't understand why it work great on my localhost server but not on my Tomcat server.

Maybe someone might help me to resolve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Bye

Comment: This does not seem a classpath problem. Have you registered the driver?

Comment: Could you share some code about how to registered your driver?